# C# Ole DB Insert SQL Cannot Work

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, ole, sql-insert

In this class , I am trying to implement a method to execute an SQL insert in a parameterized manner so as to prevent SQl injection, the result can show that the query can be executed but the database is not updated when I clicked the attached database in my project .

So how to carry out the insert command using Ole DB ? Is there any methodology and precautions when implementing this ?

The below is my code

```
    private string connectionDBString =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
```

....

```
   public void add_data(string chi_name, string eng_name, string nick_name,
        int bd_year, int bd_month, int bd_day, string home_tel, int no_of_child......
```

......

```
                    string sql = @"INSERT INTO STUDENT(CHI_NAME,ENG_NAME,NICK_NAME,BD_YYYY,BD_MM,BD_DD,HOME_TEL,NO_OF_CHILD ..)VALUES(@NEW_CHI_NAME,@NEW_ENG_NAME,@NEW_NICK_NAME,@NEW_BD_YYYY......
```

....

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NEW_CHI_NAME", chi_name));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NEW_ENG_NAME", eng_name));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NEW_NICK_NAME", nick_name));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NEW_BD_YYYY", bd_year));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NEW_BD_MM", bd_month));
```

....

```
 connection.Open();

                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (rows > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Insert New Client Success!" + "  " + rows);
                }

                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
```

.......In the app.config  , with ConnectionString included properly

```
    <add name="TestConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"

         providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

Comment: Have you tried hitting F5 when the table is opened?

Comment: I have tried but to no avail when I clicked the Access database and retrieve the data.